# Trying to Use Required HTML Attribute on Web Form; Text Disappears with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, onclick, onsubmit

I'm attempting to use Google Script to send user information from an HTML form to Google Drive.

I had a version that worked well enough, using the onclick event, but I wanted to add functionality that ensured all required fields were filled in before submission. Research on this site suggested onsubmit within the form tag, so I modified my code to use onsubmit. That's the version that appears below.

What happens is that on submission, the form completely disappears and no files are sent to Drive. I understand that onsubmit refreshes the page...but I'd like it to also recreate the previous page minus the form, and add some message about successful upload. File submission also needs to work, of course. I'd appreciate any thoughts about this.

I have looked at posts related to very similar questions and tried to implement some of the code from them, but no luck yet.  Thanks!

```
<body>
    <div id = "image" style = "background-color:#03296d">
        <h1 id = "jhh">Employment</h1>
        <h1 class = "details"><strong>Employment Opportunities</strong></h1>
        <form id="myForm" onsubmit = "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).doPost(this.parentNode);
                              return false;">

            <input id = "info" type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name">
            <input id = "info" type = "email" name="myEmail" placeholder="Email address">
            <input id = "info" type="text" name="myPhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <textarea  id = "info" type = "text" name = "myQualifications" placeholder = "Describe your qualifications" text = "wrap" cols = "40" rows = "10">
            </textarea>
            <br>
            <textarea  id = "info" type = "text" name = "myInfo" placeholder = "Any other information that would assist us in selecting you for the group interview." text = "wrap" cols = "40" rows = "10">
            </textarea>
            <input type="file" name="myFile">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Application"> 
        </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        function fileUploaded(status) {   
            document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Thank you";   
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        input { 
                display:block; 
                margin: 10px; 
               }
        textarea {
                   margin: 10px;
                 }
        jhh {
              font-family:'Gill Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              font-size:24px;
              font-weight:100;
              line-height:normal;
             }
         .details {color: #4a4a4a;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: normal;}
    </style>
</body>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var dropbox = "Applicants";

function doGet(e)
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) 
{
  try {   
    var name = form.myName;
    var folder,folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

   if (folders.hasNext()) 
    {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }    

    var blob = form.myFile;
    var contentType = blob.getContentType();
    var destinationFolder = folder.createFolder(name);
    var file = destinationFolder.createFile(blob);  
    if (contentType != "application/octet-stream") {
       file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
       return "Your submission was successfully uploaded."; 
    } else {      
       file.setDescription("No file or unsupported file type " + form.myName);
       file.setName("No file uploaded");
       return "Your submission was successfully uploaded."; 
    }
  } 
  catch (error) 
  {  
    return error.toString();
  }
}

function doPost(form) { // change to doPost(e) if you are recieving POST data
  var name = form.myName;
  var email = form.myEmail;
  var phoneNumber = form.myPhoneNumber;
  var qualifications = form.myQualifications;
  var info = form.myInfo;
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name,2,5);
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);

    if (folders.hasNext()) 
    {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
  var newSheetCopy = newSheet.copy(name + ' application');
  var newSheetCopyID = newSheetCopy.getId();
  var fileReference = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetCopyID);
  folder.addFile(fileReference);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(fileReference);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(newSheet.getId()));
  var headers = [['Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number', 'Qualifications', 'Additional Info']];
  var values = [[name, email, phoneNumber, qualifications, info]];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheetCopyID); 
  ss.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(1);
  ss.getRange('A1:E1').setValues(headers).setFontWeight('bold');
  ss.getRange('A2:E2').setWrap(true);
  ss.setColumnWidth(4, 500);
  ss.setColumnWidth(5, 500);
  ss.getRange('A2:E2').setValues(values);  
}
```

Comment: I don't see the "required" property on any of your form inputs.

Comment: Also, I think it would be easier to include ALL of your javascript separate from the HTML, not just some of it. You can handle onsubmit for the form using pure JS, and a function or to to validate the form input.

Comment: oops...I had removed the required property during troubleshooting...at this point I'm trying to make the submission work from onsubmit, and then I can implement the 'required' property

Comment: That's all the javascript...I'm using Google Script for this project

Answer (score 0):

Another note, some of your inputs share the same ID. If you're going to use ID and name, I would make them match. I would also give the submit button an ID. You may want to also look into HTML5 form input validation, which is mostly supported by browsers, but ultimately, you want the javascript (client-side) and server side code to validate your input.

```
<script>
/**
* Validates all form inputs and returns an error message as needed.
* @returns string
*/
function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById('myName').value.trim() === '') {
    return 'Name is required.';
    }
    return ''; // no error message
}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
      var error = validateForm();

      if (error !== '') {

          return false;
      }

     document.getElementById('myForm').submit();

 }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm able to validate input using both the above js and HTML5 required property. I'll implement both so that users with unsupported browsers or versions will also have their entries checked. However, I still have one of my original problems, which is that the entire page refreshes when I click submit, and the forms are not uploaded to Drive properly. I can't repost my entire updated HTML here in the comments...is there something I'm missing with onsubmit? Perhaps I should post this as a new question...

Comment: Ok...possible dumb question: to use the above validateForm() function as it is written, I'd need to give my submit an id of 'submit', correct? It seems that I wouldn't need to call the function from the form onsubmit, since it seems the function call happens from onclick of the submit button. Just want to be sure I understand...Thanks!